# If $\cos x + \cos y=1$ and $\cos x \cos y=1/4$, then find the general solutions for x and y

Tags: trigonometry

Squaring on both sides 
$$\cos^2 x + \cos^2 y + 2\cos x \cos y=1$$
I know w don’t generally square while finding general solutions, but I couldn’t see any other way 
$$\cos^2 x +\cos^2 y=1/2$$
I couldn’t solve further. How should I proceed?

Comment: Finding two numbers given product and sum is equivalent to solving a quadratic equation...

Comment: Yeah, that works, didn’t think like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint.

Can you solve for $a, b$

$$
\cases{a+b=1\\
a b = \frac 14}
$$
?